# Why isn't this accepted non-self answer pinned on top?

Tags: bug, status-completed, accepted-answer

I came across [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/513999) that practices the behavior: The accepted answer isn't submitted by the question asker, but it's not pinned on top. Why?

> [image: screenshot]

Note: For the sake of explanation, I removed post content and comment area via web front-end manipulation, otherwise my screen won't be tall enough to take the above screenshot.

Comment: The [timeline](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/514020/timeline) shows it was deleted and undeleted; maybe that has to do something with it?

Comment: @Glorfindel Related: [Deleted accepted answer pinned as top answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/148502)

Comment: Um... isn't there a rule that freehand circles should be **red**? However, one could imagine sequences of actions that *might* lead to this effect. E.g. that the poster was dissociated from the Q and the A separately. Someone who can provide the timelines of the posts could shed some light on this. Right now, one can only guess.

Comment: Is it possible that the answerer-account was merged with the asker-account? It would then be a self-answer, but then I wonder why the answer still caries the "old" user id. One currious thing is that the answer was accepted by Community: https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/514020/timeline .. when does that happen?

Comment: @Tom the original accepting user got deleted, so acceptance is moved to Community. Same happens with bounties if the user that posts the bounty is deleted.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Reproducible even with TamperMonkey disabled.

Comment: @iBugsaysReinstateMonica I realised I could test that myself lol. Oops! Looks the same to me. Interesting.

Comment: Counterexample: Old Q&A, migrated, user whom wrote accepted answer no longer active, yet [***their*** accepted answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8518/170832) rises to the top. --- This *bug* was [suggested but not implemented here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169113/282094).

Comment: @Rob Not a good example I would say. The top answer, in addition to being accepted, is also the top-scored one. You might want to bring another example where the accepted answer isn't the top-scored.

Comment: Read the first word again.

Comment: @Rob Sorry, but I still don't understand why it's a bug - top-scored and accepted answer pinned at top sounds perfectly OK.

Comment: @iBugsaysReinstateMonica If it would had the same bug, then the answer wouldn't be the top when sorting the answers by "active" or "oldest" (there are more recent answers and it isn't the oldest). Since it stays pinned the "accepted" vote really counts there. I guess that is why Rob wrote "counterexample".

Comment: @Tom Got your (and Rob's) point. Thanks

Comment: This may not be [meme-compliant](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775).

Comment: Just ran into [another example](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/a/2812/3171) of this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Funny story...

That answer and its question were posted by the same person, using two different accounts. When this was discovered, moderators deleted the sockpuppet account and the owner of the other account requested that one be deleted as well.

So in a sense, the system was doing the right thing here - not pinning a self-accepted answer - but, it was doing so for the wrong reason: with both authors gone, the relevant comparison boiled down to, `if ( null == null )`!

Naturally, there are thousands of other cases where both authors are gone but *without* sockpuppets being involved. In those cases, it's clearly undesired behavior to unpin... So starting today, those will behave normally unless the system *knows* the authors were the same.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what variable is resolving to `null` here? Presumably there's still some latent account information, or we wouldn't be seeing the distinct, "defaulted" usernames?

Comment: There's a string on the post record itself - OwnerDisplayName - that is set to "userNNNN" or whatever on user deletion; that's the fallback here. IIRC, that info is in the public data dumps too - you'll find similar logic in many queries that deal with post ownership.

Comment: I see! Interesting. (I haven't ever really played with the dumps.)

Comment: "denormalized" is probably more accurate though still wrong as in this scenario there is no longer a normal form - the field *becomes* the source of truth upon user deletion (slightly more complicated in Teams but still true for most practical purposes). The system was originally designed to work just fine without the concept of a User Account *at all*, and still retains some support for this in key places.

Comment: Sounds sensible. My initial instinct was that this was maybe not the best approach, that you'd be better off keeping the account links but just nuking all the personal info on the account and anonymising the display name. But then I realised that the denormalisation is probably part of the point: the links between different posts could be considered identifying information (especially when considering pings in any lingering comment threads under said posts)

Comment: It could be made to work either way; this was an early design decision that, initially, had as many privacy issues as a "deactivated" account system would have... We've just had a decade+ to patch them up at this point. Regardless of approach, privacy has to be an intentional goal or... It becomes an accident waiting to happen.

Comment: Yep, definitely. Glad it's taken into account.